# Running rational performance tester on a schedule

Tags: rational-performance-test

Is is possible to run rational performance tester once every hour and generate a report which contains all response times for every hour for all pages? Like this

```
hour 1: hello.html min avg max time
hour 2: hello.html min avg max time
hour 3: hello.html min avg max time
```

if you use a ordinary schedule and let it iterate once every hour all response times get lumped together in the report likes this:

```
hello.html` min avg max count=24
```

.

Would it be possible to start rpt from a script and run a specific project/schedule and then let cron run that script every hour?

Answer (score 1):

For sure, you can schedule that task using Rational Quality Manager, the new IBM's Centralized QA Management Tool. However, in the same tool you can start your test plan with a Java code that allows you to manage that.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To run the Rational Performance tester tests automatically, one can you use commandline feature that is built within tool. So if you can create window scheduler to use bat file(or unix crontab to use shell script) and the following command inserted into that file, that would solve the first bit of calling rpt test automatically.

cmdline –workspace “workspace “–project “testproj” –schedule “schedule_or_test”

For more details on the above command, refer the below link
[Executing Rational Performance tester from command line](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/how-to-schedule-rational-performance.html)

Second bit, To produce response time report automatically, there seems to be no easy way(which is shame), but one can write java custom code to log page responses time into text file.

Comment: This works for me. I found the command line plugin buried under c:\program files\IBM\ with `dir /s/b cmdline.cmd`

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that? Sounds like you are looking for a method of monitoring a running website! If so then there are much simpler ways such as adding %D in apache logformat to write out the time taken to service the page and process your web logs every hour instead :-)

If you really want to do this then don't use RPT - use JMeter or something more commandliney, would be easy then. In fact if its just loading a page then Curl on a cron would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not a single page it is a websphere portal running on an mainframe so it is not just to open up an apache config.

Haven't looked into JMeter but we have a couple of steps that must be done in the test ( log in make some stuff and logout) that we want to measure and we allready had a testflow in RPT that we use so it would be nice to reuse it even if it is not what rpt are ment for.

//Olme

Answer (score 0):

You can use several stages for the scheduler(select the scheduler, add in "user load" tab).

```
stage 1, duration 1 hour
stage 2, duration 1 hour
stage 3, duration 1 hour
```

You would get the test result with several stages. Select all the stages and right click, there's "compare" option, after compare the stages' result, it looks:

```
stage 1: hello.html min avg max time
stage 2: hello.html min avg max time
srage 3: hello.html min avg max time
```